# update mysql table based on checked checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

I have a table with a column called `extension_list` which has comma separated values in

`200,201,202,203,204` etc

If i have a loop that selects these from the database:

```
$stmt = $pbx01_pdoconn->prepare("SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = :parent_client_id ");
$stmt->execute(array(':parent_client_id' => $customerid));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($records as $result) {
    $stmt = $pbx01_pdoconn->prepare("SELECT * from extension where client_id = :client_id ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':client_id' => $result["id"]));
    $extension = $stmt->fetch();
    if($extension["type"] == 'term') {
        echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$result["name"].' ('.$extension["number"].')</a></td>
    </tr>';
    }
}
```

how can i show checkboxes next to each value and if the $extension["number"] value is in the extension_list column make the check box ticked.

also, when the checkbox is ticked and submit button is pressed, it will update the extension_list column and add that value into the comma separated list

Comment: As a note, storing comma separated values in the database is almost always a bad idea if you need to manipulate them using queries. A properly normalized structure would work way better.

Comment: Using a commma-separated list in a single column is generally bad design. It would be better to use a relation table to store that information. So you would maybe have tables `clients`, `extensions`, and `clients_x_extensions` where the latter would have the columns `client_id` and `extension_id`.

Answer (score 0):

**You should normalize your table.**

Then you can have HTML input checkboxes such as this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="extensions[]" value="<?php echo $extension['id'] ?>">`

Then, in your script, you can handle them such as this:

```
$extensions = isset($_POST['extensions'])  && is_array($_POST['extensions']) ? $_POST['extensions'] : array();
foreach($extensions as $extension) {
  // use $extension here
}
```

This should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: how can i run and update query to remove the number or add the number in the comma separated list ?

Comment: "you should normalize your table". Having a child table that just holds individual extensions, but has a foreign key back to the parent table, would be an example (1:N)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="extenstionbox[]" id="extenstionbox" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $extension['id']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($extension['id'], $extensions)) echo 'checked="checked"';?>>
```